# program stops on calling wait(); in java

Tags: java

I have synchronized this code for using wait and notify but now the program stops execution (program hangs) when I call wait() by clicking wait button. Please help, and don't suggest me different links please fix this code and answer.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener, Runnable {


    JLabel time = new JLabel();
    JButton wait = new JButton("wait");
    JButton notify = new JButton("notify");
    Thread count = new Thread(this);
    int sec=0;


    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        new Main();
    }


    public Main() {
        super("Counter");
        setSize(250,100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setVisible(true);
        add(time);
        add(wait);
        add(notify);
        notify.setEnabled(false);
        wait.addActionListener(this);
        notify.addActionListener(this);
        count.start();
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        synchronized(count) {
            if(e.getSource()==wait) {
                try
                {
                    count.wait();
                    wait.setEnabled(false);
                    notify.setEnabled(true);
                }
                catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            else if(e.getSource()==notify) {
                count.notify();
                wait.setEnabled(true);
                notify.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }
    }



    public void run() {

        synchronized (this) {           
            while(true) {
                time.setText(String.format("seconds=%d",sec));
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                sec++;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: because it is waiting on same thread you can't expect it to create implicitly new Thread on click, also you should use `equals()` to compare object not `==`

Comment: @jigar joshi Why not use == to see that it is the same button?

Comment: @JigarJoshi I'm pretty sure he's comparing references, not values. I use `==` when using `ActionListener` as well, as long as the buttons are in the same class (or have access to them in some way)

Answer (score 1):

You're blocking the EDT when you call `wait()`. When you try to `notify()`, it won't work, because the thread in charge of button events (EDT) is already waiting. You must call `notify()` on a different thread.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    synchronized(count) {
        if(e.getSource()==wait) {
            try
            {
                count.wait(); // start blocking this thread
                wait.setEnabled(false); // im pretty sure this doesnt get called until notified either
                notify.setEnabled(true);
            }
            catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if(e.getSource()==notify) {
            count.notify(); // will never get called cause this thread is blocked, waiting to be notified by another thread
            wait.setEnabled(true);
            notify.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: "You must call `notify()` from a different thread" ... this should probably be "You must call `wait()` from a different thread" since `wait()` on the Event Dispatch Thread is a no-no.

Comment: @ajb This is not my code, this is showing the portion of his code that is messing up, with comments to give details as to when and whats going on

Comment: @VinceEmigh I misinterpreted... sorry.  I've edited my comment.

Comment: @user3808922 I don't know the reason why you are calling `wait()`, so I can't really give efficient code. Like ajb said, you shouldn't be calling `wait()` on the EDT, so if you told me how your application should function, I could help you out. Please update your question with detail

Answer (score 1):

When the "wait" button is clicked, `actionPerformed` is called on the Event Dispatch Thread.  That thread must not be blocked, otherwise Swing will grind to a halt and will not be able to process any other events.  Therefore you may not call `wait()` on that thread.

If you want the "wait" button to cause some other thread to stop processing (maybe you want it to stop changing the "time" text?), you'll need to get your `actionPerformed` method to communicate with that other thread somehow; it may be sufficient to set a shared `volatile` variable that the other thread checks periodically.  But `actionPerformed` needs to return quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read a quick and easy to follow tutorial related to java concurrency:

[Jenkov Java Concurrency Tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/index.html)

And this sections explains how to use `wait()`, `notify()` and `notifyAll()` methods from an Object.

[Thread Signal](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-signaling.html)

If you let me, I advice you to read the entire (relative short) tutorial, you will understand quickly many aspects from java concurrency.